# Restoring single collection in an existing mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I'm failing miserably to be able to restore a single collection into an existing database.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with mongo version 2.6.7
There is a dump/mydbname/contents.bson based off my home directory.

If I run

```
mongorestore --collection contents --db mydbname
```

Then I get:

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
don't know what to do with file [dump]
```

If I add in the path

```
mongorestore --collection contents --db mydbname --dbpath dump/mydbname
```

Then I get

```
If you are running a mongod on the same path you should connect to that instead of direct data file access
```

I've tried various other combinations, options, etc. and just can't puzzle it out, so I'm coming to the community for help!

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If you want to restore a single collection then you have to specifiy the dump file of the collection. The dump file of the collection is found in the 'dump/dbname/' folder. So assuming your dump folder is in your current working directory, the command would go something like -

```
mongorestore --db mydbname --collection mycollection dump/mydbname/mycollection.bson
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that one already.  That gives me 'If you are running a mongod on the same path you should connect to that instead of direct data file access'.  Have also tried running this with the service started and stopped.

Comment: Works fine on mongo 3.2 too. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I think this is now done with the `--nsInclude` option:

`mongorestore --nsInclude test.purchaseorders dump/`

`dump/` is the folder with your mongodump data, `test` is the db, and `purchaseorders` is the collection.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

Answer (score 4):

Steps to restore specific collection in the mongodb.

1) Go to the directory where your dump folder exists.

2) Execute following command by modifying according to your db name and your collection name.

```
mongorestore --db mydbname --collection mycollection dump/mydbname/mycollection.bson
```

**If you get `Failed: yourdbname.collection.name: error creating indexes for collection.name: createIndex error: The field 'safe' is not valid for an index specification error`, then you can use following command:**

```
mongorestore --db mydbname --collection mycollection dump/mydbname/mycollection.bson --noIndexRestore
```

Comment: this gives me error: error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one polling interval in seconds and only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes

Answer (score 2):

If you are restoring multiple collections, you can use a loop:

```
for file in "$HOME/mongodump/dev/<your-db>/"* ; do

  if [[ "$file" != "*metadata*" && "$file" != "system.*" && "$file" != "locks.*" ]]; then

    file="$(basename "$file”)"

    mongorestore \
        --db cdt_dev \
        --collection "${file%.*}" \   # filename w/o extension
        --host "<your-host>" \
        --authenticationDatabase "<your-auth-db>" \
        -u "user" \
        -p "pwd" \
        "$HOME/mongodump/dev/<your-db>/$file"

  fi;

done
```